# Confusion about tensor derivation in wiki article

Tags: tensors

I can't follow the derivation of the gradient of a vector field in cylindrical coordinates from [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_%28continuum_mechanics%29#Cylindrical_polar_coordinates)

My problem is with the $e_r \otimes e_\theta$ term.

Expanding the definition from a couple of lines above gives:

$$\big(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta} - v_k \Gamma_{\theta r}^k\big)g^r \otimes g^\theta$$

$$=\big(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta} - v_\theta \Gamma_{\theta r}^\theta\big)e_r \otimes (\frac1re_\theta)$$

$$=\frac1r\big(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta} - v_\theta \frac1r\big)e_r \otimes e_\theta$$

But the article gets

$$=\frac1r\big(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta} - v_\theta\big)e_r \otimes e_\theta$$

I think this difference might be to do with the Christoffel symbols.
I used $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial u^j} \cdot g^k$ whereas the article uses $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial u^k} \cdot g_k$. (Making the change gives me a different error). Is the article version correct? Using my definition (from a textbook) makes the identity from the article seem simpler to me:

$$\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial u^j} \cdot g_k = -\frac{\partial g^k}{\partial u^j} \cdot g_i$$

(from the article)

$$\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial u^j} \cdot g^k = -\frac{\partial g^k}{\partial u^j} \cdot g_i$$
$$ 0 = \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial u^j} \cdot g^k + \frac{\partial g^k}{\partial u^j} \cdot g_i$$
$$ 0 = \frac{\partial (g_i \cdot g^k)}{\partial u^j} $$
$$ 0 = \frac{\partial (\delta_{i k})}{\partial u^j} $$
$$ = 0 $$

(with the textbook definition on the left hand side)

How is the wiki result derived? I know it correlates with at least [one other source](http://www.continuummechanics.org/cm/cylindricalcoords.html).

Comment: in not a good idea to use $\delta$ instead of $\partial$

Comment: @janmarqz thanks, I'm new to latex. I'll edit it.

Comment: This is done most easily by calculating the ricci rotation coefficients probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem - while the article uses the notation $\textbf{v} = v^j \textbf{g}_j$ above, in the expression for the gradient it is implied that $\textbf{v} = v_j \hat{\textbf{e}}^j$ i.e. the covariant componenets are being taken with respect to the **unit** basis vectors.

Using the Christoffel symbols from the article, I get
$$=\frac1r\big(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta} - rv_\theta\big)e_r \otimes e_\theta$$

where $v_i$ is with respect to the usual basis vectors. Using $v_{<i>}$ for the components with respect to the unit basis vectors then gives

$$=\frac1r\big(\frac{\partial v_{<r>}}{\partial \theta} - r\frac1rv_{<\theta>}\big)e_r \otimes e_\theta$$

which agrees with the article.